# Not all code return value in this method

Tags: c#, .net

This is the method i was using to check if there is a match of title in the data table:

```
public static bool checkBook(DataTable dt, String title)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            String checktitle = dr["Title"].ToString();
            if (title == checktitle)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //do something
        return false;
     }
}
```

but there is a problem, i try to use try and catch but why there is no value return?

Comment: Don't abuse exception, especially unspecifed ones : use tests instead.

Comment: The foreach is unnescessary (and the root of your problem), as it will always return on the first occurence, however if there are 0 rows, it will never return a value.

Comment: My guess you want to do something like this `return dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(r => r["Title"].ToString()).Any(t => t == title);`

Comment: dont forget to mark answer as accpeted if you got the info you want ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is **error because if there is no row in datatable nothing get returned form code** so that you need to `return false` like as below in code ,

**Refine code for you :**

```
    public static bool checkBook(DataTable dt, String title)
    {
      bool returnval= false;
      try 
      {

         foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                String checktitle = dr["Title"].ToString();
                if (title == checktitle)
                {
                    returnval= true;
                }

        }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
     //do something
    }
    return returnval;
   }
```

Answer (score 6):

You aren't returning anything from the `try` block in the situation where nothing is enumerated from `dt.Rows`.

Outside the foreach in the try block, you simply need to add `return false;`

Answer (score 2):

*What happens if there are no rows in the data?

What gets returned then?*